# chrome won't install because of architecture?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

I am trying to install Chrome on a 64 bit, see all info below. I also tried this on Ubuntu and get the same thing. Chrome won't install because of the architecture. I am some what knowledgeable with Linux, but I never got into 64bit on a pi. I think it is because my architecture is aarch64 and Chrome needs it to be amd64. Chromeium isn't an option or I wouldn't be in this 64 bit mess. When I ran Ubuntu there was a wget install amd64 but I don't know anything about that. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
(--install): package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64) 
Errors were encountered while processing:`

Pi3 B+
Linux debian-buster-64 4.19.34-v8-43958a67195d-bis+ #2 SMP PREEMPT
Tue Apr 9 13:27:57 GMT 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" 
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux" 
VERSION_ID="10" VERSION="10 (buster)" VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian Distributor ID: Raspbian    
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch) Release: 9.8 Codename: stretch
```

Comment: Correct, chrome will not install (or work, even if you could get it installed) because it has been compiled for x86-64.  There is no way around that.

Answer (score 5):

chrome is designed for ×86 processors only
the RPi is an ARM processor

but you can give chromium a shot.

Comment: There are ARM based chromebooks and android devices, although that really doesn't make much difference -- there's still no publicly available version that will fly on a pi.